# change background image when mouse over

Tags: javascript, html

I have a requirement in HTML5.

[image]

News,Business,People and Branding are 4 images and i added all into the background image.
When i mouse hover on the News image, Background image should change and mouseout should show old background image.
I dont know what to writen on the mouseover function.

please check the code and let me know where changes are required.


    
         Intranet Application

```
<style>     
    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        }

    #BG {
        background-image: url('img/asianwoman.jpg');
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        min-width: 100%;
        background-size: 100% 100%;                             
    }

</style>

<script type="text/JavaScript">

    function mouseOverFunction(){

    }

    function mouseOutFunction(){            

    }       
</script>
```

Comment: No need for javascript. See the :hover pseudo element: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Answer (score 3):

If the requirement is that one element affects the background of another, you will require JS. Assuming id="news" is the triggering element and id="BG" is the receiving element:

```
document.getElementById("news").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  document.getElementById("BG").style.backgroundImage = "url(img/southamericangrandmother.jpg)";
}, false);
document.getElementById("news").addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
   document.getElementById("BG").style.backgroundImage = "";
}, false);
```

Comment: It does work. See an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6YEAG/). If it doesn't work in your site, it's possible that there's some element on top of #BG that prevents the hover from happening. Seeing the actual HTML code would help.

Comment: in my case, i have a background in main div class and mouse over in the another image (News image), to change the main div class background.

Comment: In this case use javascript: handle mouseover/mouseout of image and change bg of needed div.

Comment: For the ones not so familiar with Java-Script: The snippet of this answer must be placed **below** of the referenced elements "news" and "BG".

Answer (score 2):

Javascript

```
var e = document.getElementById('id');
e.style.backgroundImage = 'url(image.gif)';
```

JQuery

```
$('#id').css('background-image','url(image.gif)');
```

CSS (3)

```
#id{
  background-image:url(image.gif);
}

#id:hover{
  background-image:url(mouseoverimage.gif);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hC76C/)

```
 html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    }

   #BG {
      background-image: url('http://www.hdwallpapers3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Flower-wallpaper-29.jpg') ;
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;

   }

 #BG:hover {
    background-image: url('http://radiantq.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/software_box.png');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript code ..

```
    document.getElementById('BG').onmouseover = function()        
     {        
      document.getElementById('BG').style.backgroundImage = "url('image.png') no-repeat";
     };
```

Answer (score -1):

simply do with css

with effect

```
#BG {
    background-image: url('img/asianwoman.jpg');
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%; 
    transition:background 2s;
    -webkit-transition:background 2s; /* Safari */                            
}

  #BG:hover {
    background-image: url('img/yourNewImage.jpg');
  }
```

Comment: as explained by @np_ : This can not work if the mouse-over of one element should effect the background of an other element.