# Changing body background Image when mouse over a text with JS

Tags: javascript, html, background

Basically i am trying with JS to change body image when the mouse pass over a text, in the code i show you now i used a line to change body color, but i don't know the syntax to make it change image, so i tried to write a line for the image and i commented it, coz i dunno if it is correct or not, here is the code with the WORKING change color when mouse over.

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-4 offset-xl-4 text-center">
            <p onmouseover="return bg1();"><a href="#" type="onmouseover" class="dimen">Sfondo 1</a></p>
            <p onmouseover="return bg2();"><a href="#" type="onmouseover" class="dimen">Sfondo 2</a></p>
            <p onmouseover="return bg3();"><a href="#" type="onmouseover" class="dimen">Sfondo 3</a></p>
            <p onmouseover="return bg4();"><a href="#" type="onmouseover" class="dimen">Sfondo 4</a></p>



        </div>
    </div>

</body>

<script>
    //  document.getElementById("bgchange").style.backgroundImage= url(../media/battimani.jpg);


    function bg1(){

        document.getElementById("bgchange").style.backgroundColor = "#66ff66";

    }

    function bg2(){

        document.getElementById("bgchange").style.backgroundColor = "#eb4034";

    }
    function bg3(){

        document.getElementById("bgchange").style.backgroundColor = "#ebde34";

    }

    function bg4(){

        document.getElementById("bgchange").style.backgroundColor = "#3440eb";

    }

</script>
```

copied just the body, can u tell me how to write properly the first commented line inside the script? i want to use that in 4 different way like the 4 different color, thank you =)

ps: just started learning js a week ago so my level is basic basic

Comment: Why don't you try it out and get back if it doesn't work?

Comment: DUPLICATE https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015573/change-background-image-when-mouse-over

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  document.getElementById("bgchange").style.backgroundImage = "url(../media/battimani.jpg)";
```

Comment: omg it's working ahahaha, damn it was that simple, just the " " thank you very much, i have another question if it doesn't bothery you, how to add some sort of css to make the image fluid with the browser dimension? is that even possible ?

Comment: did you mean image which can fit any screen size?

Comment: yes, by resizing screen dimension, the image resize as well like the img-fluid in boostrap

Comment: add HTML
<img src="img_nature.jpg" alt="Nature" class="responsive" width="600" height="400">
add CSS
.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

Comment: here is an example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_responsive

Comment: guide => https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_responsive.asp